# Facebook login shows an additional confirmation popup on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login, ios11

I have implemented login through facebook using facebook SDK for swift. It works as expected on iOS 10.3, but on iOS 11 it shows and additional popup that asks the user to allow sign in through facebook.com.

[image: security confirmation]

This adds one more step in the login process that slows down the login process. Is there a way how to to configure the app to allow this by default, thus remove the annoying popup?

I am using facebook-sdk-swift 0.2.0 (FBSDK version is 4.26.0) added through cocoa pods.

Configuration in `info.plist`:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>XXXXX</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>facebook</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Code in `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

`LoginController` has a custom login button with this in handler:

```
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.loginBehavior = .native
    loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile, .userFriends, .email, .custom("user_location"), .custom("user_education_history"), .custom("user_work_history") ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
    }
```

I created an app from scratch to test it, shared on [GitHub](https://github.com/MilanNosal/MilanTestApp). Still does the same.

Comment: I use facebook sdk via pod file too in ios 11 but i didn't faced any kind of problem could you share how can you integrate your facebook login ?

Comment: exactly it re-directed automatically

Comment: I think problem is in you plist file.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/ maybe you can check this link and the inspect plist configuration

Comment: well, I am not able to see anything that I would miss.. and the login is otherwise working.. it seems just like some security tweak, although I don't understand why it works for you (and some other apps), but not in my case.. maybe it is a problem of the SDK version?

Comment: i use these pod 'FBSDKLoginKit' maybe the version of your pod is the issue

Comment: which version do you have?

Comment: Using FBSDKShareKit (4.24.0)

Comment: I tried to create a test app from the scratch to see if there is not any side effects, but it still behaves the same: https://github.com/MilanNosal/MilanTestApp 

are you using swift or objc?

Comment: I use swift on my projects

Comment: Have you get any solution for prevent additional popup i face same problem .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

OK, so after several useless experiments I have been able to find a way to achieve what my client wanted. Aforementioned behavior is the result of a newer version of FBSDK. Once I downgraded from FBSDK 4.26.0 to 4.24.0 (Swift SDK version does not matter), the popup stopped showing. So if you are facing the same problem, and your clients (or you) don't want this popup, this might be a solution for you too.

I don't think facebook guys did this by accident, and this popup can allow some new iOS 11 feature. However, I was not able to distinguish any real new functionality - I only noticed that the newer version does not give you a choice if you want to login using native app or safari, but goes directly for the safari login. But since that was a requirement by my client as well, for me the choice was quite natural.

The message is a standard message used by `SFAuthenticationSession` to ask the user for permissions to access safari (excerpt from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfauthenticationsession)):

> If an application uses SFAuthenticationSession, users are prompted by a dialog to give explicit consent, allowing the application to access the website's data in Safari.

**UPDATE:**

Apparently, Safari uses the "CFBundleName" property as the display name for this dialog. This is usually set to ${PRODUCT_NAME} which equals the last portion of your app's bundle identifier, but you can change it to whatever you like. Of course it is advisable to set it to the actual display name of your app.

Comment: Hey, do you think we can change the message in this alert somehow?

Comment: @rv7284 that message is a standard message used by `SFAuthenticationSession` to ask the user for permissions to access safari (excerpt from docs: `If an application uses SFAuthenticationSession, users are prompted by a dialog to give explicit consent, allowing the application to access the website's data in Safari.`). So no, I do not think that there would be way to configure this very important security consent dialog

Comment: As you mentioned, since the alert is shown deliberately, I would discourage trying to hide it (skip it)...

Comment: its okay to show this popup but I want to know that how to edit app name? it seems that app name is not a nickname of app but a bundle name so its confusing

Comment: @Jigar you'll need to change the `Product Name` in your App Build Settings under the packaging section.

Comment: @vignesh that is not accurate, my product name is different from what appears there, it still shows the bundle id

Comment: @GustavoParrado hmm that was the change that worked for me. How did you get it to change then?

Comment: @GustavoParrado did you find a solution to this problem? We have an app with an internal id which is very different from the product name, so it's very confusing to our users when Facebook SDK shows internal id in this popup

Comment: @AndersEmil no, another dev updated something but I never got to know what exactly

Comment: @GustavoParrado I found a solution in the meantime. Apparently Safari uses the "CFBundleName" property as the display name for this dialog. This is usually set to ${PRODUCT_NAME}, which is the internal identifier. I fixed my problem by changing it to the display name of my app and it works perfectly. FFR: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/221#issuecomment-405529681

Comment: @AndersEmil that's a very valuable info. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AndersEmil feel free to update my answer with your insights

Comment: In my case CFBundleName was missing in Info.plist (app was in production and with correct name so CFBundleName is not required). I set CFBundleName to $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME) and now dialog works OK - as app name in dialog is not used target name but real app name.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the **iOS 11.x** update, **Facebook SDK 0.3.0** is using `SFAuthenticationSession` which result in an Alert to give explicit consent, allowing the application to access the website's data in Safari.

Tried this on **iOS 10.x**, no Alert!

If you want to get rid of the popup, you should downgrade the Facebook SDK to **0.2.0** , and since the **Facebook swift SDK** still depends on the **Objective C SDK** you should force downgrading these ones as well to the version **4.22.1**

**Before Downgrade:**

```
pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.3.0'
pod 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.3.0'
pod 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.3.0'
```

**After Downgrade:**

```
pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.2.0'
pod 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.2.0'
pod 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.2.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.22.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.22.1'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.22.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FacebookLogin 0.5.0

Changing the `Product Name` under the target's Build Settings to the desired text worked.

Also, on my plist `Bundle display name` and `Bundle name` have `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`