# Previously unseen facebook login prompt. Changes to sdk?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

As part of a sign up / sign in flow on an iOS app, we run the facebook sdk, but as of yesterday, with no changes made on our side, the facebook login prompt has changed from the previous standard prompt to a different one, which says "This allows the app and website to share information about you".

[Image reference here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVLHn.png)

This message, compared to the previous one that read something like "app_name will receive x, y and z", is clearly less tap-incentivising.

We haven't been able to locate the where and how of this change yet - is this anything you have experienced as well and if so, is that just the way it is?

Answer (score 3):

See my [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451983/facebook-login-shows-an-additional-confirmation-popup-on-ios-11) - it's the result of the new iOS 11 changes to Safari View Controller. There are two options for you - either go with the changes and leave it as it is, or downgrade to a lower version of facebook SDK.

Comment: Yep. Should be sorted out