# IOS - FB sharing opens safari dialog box for login

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So, in my app I can successfully share content. I have a question though.

1. User has not logged in FB from anywhere in the app
2. User has the FB app installed on his phone.
3. When I click share, I am being prompted to login using the FB in safari.

Can I skip no.3? And let the user get the login details from FB app on his phone?

All I do for sharing is :

```
-(void) userTappedOnFBLink:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"FB share");

    FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:SHARE_URL];

    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self.parentViewController
                                 withContent:content
                                    delegate:self];
}
```

Comment: Did you update you plist file to support [Facebook's url schemes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios) (see section 4)?

Comment: @DocForNoc yes I have - as I said user does not login from the app though. Just shares, but shouldn't it use SSO and get login from native fb app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47054319/5461400

Comment: `SLComposeViewController` was deprecated in iOS 11.0 @ghostrider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only share why don't use SLComposeViewController? Is native and don't use safari. Also works with twitter.

```
import Social
```

Create the SLComposeViewController:

```
if let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
    vc.setInitialText("Your post text") //Optional
    vc.add(UIImage(named: "YourImageName")!) //Optional
    vc.add(URL(string: "Your url")) //Optional
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Only share yes, let me try it!

Answer (score 0):

See my similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46451983/2912282) - the new flow is result of updated FBSDK. If you downgrade FBSDK to 4.24.0, you should get an option for app login again.